# Elisp: Asking yes-or-no in interactive commands

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

I'm new to Emacs and am trying to write a few Emacs Lisp functions.

I'd like to write a function that takes two parameters and can handle being interactive. However, one of the parameters is a boolean — it'd be perfect if I could use `(y-or-no-p)`, but `(interactive)` doesn't seem to have a character code for that.

Any ideas?

**Update:** I'm using GNU Emacs 23.

Also, here's what my function looks like so far:

```
(defun foo (str bool)
  (interactive "sSome text: \nsDo the thing?")
  (some-func str)
  (if bool (some-other-func str)))
```

Comment: When a function takes a boolean parameter, it is common in Emacs to use the prefix argument for that (`(interactive "sSome text:\nP")`, there is no extra prompt). This gives a better user experience (one less prompt in the most common case, more consistent with basic Emacs commands). Press `C-u` or `M-1` any of many other prefix argument combinations before the command to pass `t`, don't do it to pass `nil`. Arrange for `nil` to be the common case.

Comment: Interesting. Thanks, Gilles! (You should answer with that and the code for it so I could accept that as the answer.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ah, found it.

```
(defun foo (str bool)
  (interactive
    (list (read-string "Some text: ")
          (y-or-n-p "Do the thing? ")))
  (some-func str)
  (if bool (some-other-func str)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure what you're asking, but I can't find a function called y-or-no-p.  Did you mean yes-or-no-p?

That seems to do what I would expect.

Comment: `y-or-no-p` is a shorter version of `yes-or-no-p`, at least in Emacs 23.

Comment: `y-or-n-p` (`n`, not `no`) asks the user to type `y` or `n`, whereas `yes-or-no-p` requires the complete word (`yes` or `no`) followed by Enter.

Comment: Obviously a typo.  The question asked about `y-or-no-p`.